# Is it possible to reduce lower belly fat without reducing the fat at other parts of the body?

Tags: body-fat

I want to reduce the fat at my lower belly, but not at other parts of my body. Is this even possible? What exercise/diet routine that I can follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Fat is stored energy and is not relevant to the body section or organ it is stored on. Your body's metabolic system will pull the stored energy from wherever it wants to when it needs the excess energy. Many people do report that fat loss occurs in the order of first on, last off ..however this is purely anecdotal and not scientific